# Can we ask SEO questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions, seo

I had this [question closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143246/seo-links-from-facebook-delicious-digg-etc-are-useful-for-google-pr-closed). No problem for me, I understood I can not ask SEO questions on SO.

Today I look at SO and see this one: [Can you trick GoogleBot by writing CSS-invisible keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027381/can-you-trick-googlebot-by-writing-css-invisible-keywords).

Is this about programming? Isn't this SEO?

So why has it not been closed too?

Comment: Directly-applicable question: [Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32545/which-seo-questions-should-be-closed-as-non-programming-non-admin) (And FWIW, I voted to close. If nothing else, questions about "tricking the googlebot" are unlikely to be answerable in any provable way.

Comment: Also related: [Is SEO a sysadmin or developer issue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30924/is-seo-a-sysadmin-or-developer-issue/30926)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It probably should have been closed. In fact, I'll go ahead and vote to close it after I type this.

SO isn't perfect. Sometimes questions are closed when they shouldn't be, and left open when they should.

---

> ### closed as off-topic by Jon B, Shog9, Michael Todd, Michael Petrotta, BalusC 38 mins ago

Answer (score 27):

SEO questions should be asked on the [**Pro Webmasters, tagged with**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but I didn't ask where SEO questions should go. I asked why my SEO question was closed, and the other one is still open.